# Is there a way to make an arbitrary number of regex replacements in a single iteration?

Tags: c++, regex, algorithm

Say I have a string `s` and want to make N replacements:

```
[regex_1] --> [str_1]

[regex_2] --> [str_2]

...

[regex_N] --> [str_N]
```

Is there a more efficient way than creating `N` `regex_iterator` objects? Because if I did something like

```
std::vector<std::regex_iterator> reps = { 
   std::regex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), [regex_1]), 
   std::regex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), [regex_2]), 
   ..., 
   std::regex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), [regex_N])};
```

then the `N` initialization of all those `regex_iterator` objects will each involve iterating over the characters of `s`, which is needless repetition.

Comment: No, you would need some algorithm/library to merge those regex together.

Comment: Is there no such thing in the standard library or Boost?

Comment: What do you intend to do in the case that, e.g., placing `str_1` into a position where `regex_1` matched creates a match for one of the other regexes that wasn't there to begin with...? Do you only want to replace matches that were there in the original string, or do you want to replace newly-created matches as well (in which case the order you process them in is significant, and a merged regex is not a likely possibility)?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what result you expect.

If what you are looking for is to find sequential non-overlapping occurrences of any of the `N` patterns, then the multiple iterator solution is not only inefficient; it is incorrect.

On the other hand, if you wanted to rescan for patterns after replacement, then you could order the scans (as in the example), but it would be only a partial rescan. A precise and efficient solution is possible but not easy with the C++ regex library; a precise and not-so-efficient solution is to repeatedly find and replace the first of the disjunction of the patterns until no pattern can be found.

Either way, you would want a regex which represents the disjunction (set of alternatives) of the candidate patterns, and which lets you identify which pattern matched. If you don't depend heavily on captures, you could do this by creating the disjunct (with string concatenation on the patterns):

```
(pattern1)|(pattern2)|...|(patternN)
```

And after the match, you only need to determine which capture has a defined value by iterating through the submatches and looking at their `matched` members. Internal captures are possible, of course, but the numbering of captures makes the construct a bit fragile. It is possible to programmatically determine the number of captures in a regex (see `basic_regex::mark_count`), so you could create a multipattern search-and-replace object without *too* much work.

Comment: Disjunction is an alternative, but depending on the implementation, it is unlikely that you get better than scanning with n regex in the failing case. The advantage here is that you only need to deal with one regex object.

Comment: @nhahtdh: depends on how frequent the patterns are in the target. If they are very sparse, the disjunction is probably a win, since the non-matching segments of the target only needs to be scanned once. If you had a good DFA implementation, it would definitely be a win, but you probably don't.